# How can I access "self" in a JavaScript class?

Tags: javascript

*Note*:  I do *not* want to re-bind the `this` keyword.  I would like for `this` to reference the calling object.  I would, however, *also* like to be able to reference the instance of the class in which my method is defined.  How can I access the instance?

In JavaScript, the `this` keyword refers to the calling object.  So, when I define a class:

```
class A {
    x = 5;
    printx() {
        console.log(this.x);
    }
}
```

Then when I call the `printx` method directly from an instance of `A`, I get 5:

```
a = new A();
a.printx();
```

But when I call `printx` from a different context, `this.x` isn't `a.x`, it might be `window.x` or something else:

```
b = a.printx;
b(); // TypeError: this is undefined
```

I want to define `printx` in such a way that calling `b` will `console.log(5)`.  I.e., I want to get the `self` behavior from Python.  How do I refer to `self` in JavaScript?

Comment: The top answer here is much more complete that the ones linked in the top: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20279484/how-to-access-the-correct-this-inside-a-callback

Comment: @felipou the answer in that question never defines a `class`.  I realize this is just syntactic sugar over old-style javascript classes, but it makes the answers in your link difficult to parse.  i.e. in order to know the answer to my (simple) question, I must understand difficult and deep concepts and also grok the history of the javascript language.

Comment: "this is not possible" is also an acceptable answer.

Comment: it's very possible, though usually it's best to avoid the scenario. (aka don't do `b = a.printx;`)

Comment: @KevinB my specific use case is that I'm using my class method as a callback.  (i.e. the method gets passed in as a parameter to another function)

Comment: Right, in cases such as that, you pass a different function that calls the method. For example, `foo={() => a.printx()}` (in a react context.) in vanilla it'd be something like:  `.then(() => a.printx())`

Comment: @KevinB "it's very possible, but avoid" - would you mind elaborating on this?  Are you suggesting that there are common scenarios where I might want to have my `printx` method print `.x` from *a different object*?  As a python programmer, one might do something like `A.printx(something_else_with_an_x_property)` to get similar behavior to the above (i.e. the `self` in `printx` would not necessarily be an instance of `A`, it could be whatever I want in the context of using it.)  However, I see this sort of thing only *very rarely*...

Comment: arrow functions would generally be the way of solving this, however that's not a thing for class methods *yet,* so in your case you would need a constructor that does something along the lines of `this.printx = () => console.log(this.x)` or `this.printx = this.printx.bind(this)`, causing the function referenced by this.printx to be directly bound to that instance rather than the context of the reference.

Comment: this may actually be a thing now, not sure... haven't been keeping up with the js releases the last few years. if it is, then  you'd simply change `printx() {` to `printx = () => {`

Answer (score 5):

Use `function.prototype.bind` to bind the function to the context when you assign `b`

```js
class A {
    x = 5;
    printx() {
        console.log(this.x);
    }
}

let a = new A()
let b = a.printx.bind(a)

b()
```